# For Apache, what Linux command do I type to watch performance in real time?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, performance

What command can I type with Linux where I can watch Apache HTTP web server load in real time?

BACKGROUND: I can type 'top'. That let's me watch overall server load (just look at inverse of Idle % and consider it over a period of time). However, I need to know how to see when Apache is running into critical load and may run out of process handles or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [apachetop](http://code.google.com/p/apachetop/) is an open source initiative for monitoring the apache server itself
- [wtop/logrep](http://code.google.com/p/wtop/) is an open source initiative for retrospective
  analysis and realtime serving performance monitoring

Answer (score 2):

`mod_status` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html)) provides a web-accessible list of Apache processes and the requests they're handling.

Example output:

- http://apache.org/server-status/
- http://apache.org/server-status/?auto